# Using the ROM megafunction in VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I have created a ROM megafunction using the MegaWizard plug-in Manager. This created a new file which I named rom.vhd.

My code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity first is
port(
PC: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
data : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
clock : in STD_LOGIC
);
end first;

architecture behavioral of first is
begin 

rom_inst : rom PORT MAP (PC, clock, data);  

end behavioral;
```

I get the error: Error (10482): VHDL error at first.vhd(15): object "rom" is used but not declared

How can I fix this problem so VHDL recognizes that I have a ROM in my external file named ROM.vhd?

Comment: You likely need to `use` it, in the same way you use any other entities declared in other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions, the first is to use components to define `rom`, place this code in your architecture's declaration, between `architecture` and `begin`.

```
component rom is
port (
    PC: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    data : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    clock : in STD_LOGIC
);
```

The second solution uses VHDL-93 syntax instead. Simply replace your instantiation with:

```
rom_inst : entity work.rom PORT MAP (PC, clock, data);
```

I prefer this syntax, but components are more flexible. You *need* components when instantiating block from Verilog, an IP core or a netlist. Components can also be binded differently trough configuration blocks.

Comment: Just realized you used a megafunction. The second technique only works with vhdl files that are in your project.